# Как заменить "100 100 50 50 20" в переборе вариантов выдачи суммы банкоматом на "100х2 50х2 20х1"

Tags: java, алгоритм, рекурсия, методы

У меня есть рекурсивный метод, который перебирает и выводит все возможные варианты выдачи запрошенной суммы. Доступные банкноты: 100, 50, 20.

```
public String getOptionsCombinationBanknotes (int amount, int maxValue, String valueList) {
            if (amount == 0) {
                System.out.println(valueList);
            } else {
                if ((maxValue >= 100) && (amount >= 100)) {
                    getOptionsCombinationBanknotes(amount - 100, 100, valueList + " 100");
                }
                if ((maxValue >= 50) && (amount >= 50)) {
                    getOptionsCombinationBanknotes(amount - 50, 50, valueList + " 50");
                }
                if (amount >= 20) {
                    getOptionsCombinationBanknotes(amount - 20, 20, valueList + " 20");
                }
            }
        return valueList;
    }
```

При сумме 150 я получаю вывод:

```
100 50
50 50 50
50 20 20 20 20 20
```

Мне же нужен вывод в формате.

```
100(x1) 50(x1)
50(x3)
50(x1) 20(x5)
```

Но так же, что бы это работало для любой суммы, кратные этим номиналам. Есть ли такая возможность для рекурсивного метода ? Я перепробовал много вариантов, но все ломается. Или надо переписывать метод ?

Comment: Вы сами понимаете, как этот метод работает?

Comment: `Почему в данном методе return valueList возвращает пустоту ?` он возвращает то, что в него передали.

Comment: `Разве он не должен так же возвращать полный результат ?` - что такое "полный результат" ? Это разве строка?

Comment: `Но так же, что бы это работало для любой суммы.` это не будет работать для любой суммы. Например, для суммы 25 это не сработает.

Comment: `Или надо переписывать метод ?` если вам нужен другой результат, значит вам придется менять код.

Comment: @tym32167 через debug разорался с работой рекурсивного метода. Я имел виду, можно ли не убирать рекурсивный метод для достижения результата ? Ведь если код рабочий, то каким то образом, его можно и под нужный результат подкорректировать. Тут возможно кроется идея работы со счетчиками, которые и будут являться множителями, но вот только с множителем у меня выдается только 1 вариант, так как я уже не смогу использовать valueList в вызове метода. Мне не хватает широты мышления, что бы додумать эту идею. Поэтому и спрашиваю тут

Comment: @tym32167 по поводу любой суммы поправил. С пустотой тоже разобрался и тоже поправил.

Comment: Раз вывод нужен такой, то valuelist нужно по-другому формировать. Можно в него класть пары (банкнота;счётчик). Собственно, для всего трех известных номиналов достаточно три счётчика, а не список. И в результате выйдет так, как tym32167 сделал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавим счетчики в ваш код и будем их передавать из итерации в итерацию, чтобы в итоге собрать строку с ними и положить в результаты.

```
public void getCombinations(int amount, int maxValue, int count20, int count50, int count100, List<String> result)
{
    if (amount < 0) return;

    if (amount == 0)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (count100 > 0) sb.Append($"100(x{count100}) ");
        if (count50 > 0) sb.Append($"50(x{count50}) ");
        if (count20 > 0) sb.Append($"20(x{count20})");
        result.Add(sb.ToString());
        return;
    }

    if ((maxValue >= 100) && (amount >= 100))
        getCombinations(amount - 100, 100, count20, count50, count100 + 1, result);

    if ((maxValue >= 50) && (amount >= 50))
        getCombinations(amount - 50, 50, count20, count50 + 1, count100, result);

    if (amount >= 20)
        getCombinations(amount - 20, 20, count20 + 1, count50, count100, result);
}
```

Проверка

```
var ret = new List<String>();
getCombinations(150, 100, 0, 0, 0, ret);
foreach (var line in ret) Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Результат

```
100(x1) 50(x1) 
50(x3) 
50(x1) 20(x5)
```

Код написан на C#, но так написан, что у вас не должно быть трудностей с понимаием алгоритма.

Comment: `if (amount == 0)` не срабатывает в данном варианте. Значение уменьшается до -50 и далее срабатывает условие `if (amount < 0) return;`. По итогу часть комбинаций пропускается и не записывается

Comment: В каком варианте? Какие значения на входе функции? Какие именно комбинации пропущены? Я выложил код и результат выполнения кода идентичный тому, что вы запросили.

Comment: Входные данные `150, 100, 0, 0, 0, ret`. Итог ничего не выводит. При `200, 100, 0, 0, 0, ret` выдает `[100(x1)] [100(x1) 50(x1)] [100(x1)] [100(x2)] [100(x2) 50(x1)] [100(x1) 50(x1)] [100(x2) 50(x1)] [100(x2) 50(x2)] ` . Код полностью идентичен вашему

Comment: Всё выводит [как надо](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ldhp.png), вы видимо неправильно скопировали мой код. Покажите ваш код, который вы запускаете.

Comment: на java тоже [все прекрасно работает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xph9h.png), ищите проблему у себя в коде @Tokamo

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lzTgRSf

Comment: @Tokamo смотрите вот на эту строчку у себя `if (count20 > 0) sb.append("20(x" + count20 + ")");` - вы там не тот счетчик пишете

Comment: Все, извиняюсь. Затупил я. Работает как надо. Спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: @Tokamo на здоровье. Хорошо, что разобрались